# Issue fetching data in Nuxt 3 server route

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, fetch, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I'm trying to fetch data from an API using Nuxt 3 and can successfully do so when fetching from the API in my page component, but I'm getting an issue when trying to fetch the same data from the API in a server route. Here's the fetch call in my page:

```
const { data: get_data } = await useFetch('https://example.com/api', {
    headers: {
        'x-api-key': 'theapikey'
    }
});
```

This successfully returns JSON from the endpoint, i.e. 'get_data' has data which I can then loop through. However, I want the fetch call to be in a server route file so I can protect the API key I need to pass to the API. Here's the code in my server route file:

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) =>
{

const { api_key } = useRuntimeConfig();

const { data } = await $fetch('https://example.com/api', {
    headers: {
        'x-api-key': api_key
    }
});

return data;
});
```

If I then try to fetch the data from the server route file in my page component using the below:

```
const { data: get_data } = await useFetch('/api/test-route');
```

I get no data back at all...i.e. outputting 'get_data' doesn't display anything. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you mind sharing which external API you are using for your app? I did the same thing with my project. I am using the Shipstation API and I perform the $fetching of orders inside the server folder and it is working just fine. No issues at all

Comment: Hi @ReaganM - the external API was the issue, thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I tried with another external API and that worked fine. Strange that the initial external API worked in the page and not the server route file, but that's all sorted now